# Single Input Form Submit GET to /route/:attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to redirect a user to the route: `/:singular`. The form itself only has one field with an id of 'singular', and a button. I have tried to use CoffeeScript and JS but that didn't seem to work quite right as I had to take the input out of a form tag because it would submit and there would be `/?singular`, so if you press `enter` nothing happened, which isn't what I want.

```
<div class = "form">
  <%= text_field_tag :singular, params[:singular], name: nil %>
  <%= submit_tag "Pluralize!", name: nil, id: 'pluralize' %>
</div>

<% if @plural %>
  <div class = "plural">
    <%= "#{@plural} is the plural of #{@singular}" %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

This is the coffeescript I was trying:

```
$ ->
  $('#pluralize').click->
    document.location.href = "/" + $('#singular').val()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're aiming to do here but I think the problems you'll be facing are...

**Mixing standard html forms and RESTFul access**

By this I mean you are using html form components which will have their own serialization behaviours and javascript, which is your own custom way of processing the input values, against your rails route which takes a very simple variable.

When you have a route in Rails such as `/:myvar` then rails will match against the route and enter the value after the `/` into the `params` hash, then call the respective controller action on it. When you submit a normal html form it will serialize it's contents and format the url like so `/?myvar=val`. What you're therefore seeing when you submit your form is the form automatically trying to fetch the `singular` value and sending it as a parameter in the url. Obviously rails is expecting a simple plaing `/[value]` url when instead you're sending `/?myvar=[value]`. Make a decision and decide on it.

**Not preventing default actions**

The next part you may be slipping up on is your form submit button continuing to submit despite your attached javascript. When you click the button, you need to specifically state that you do not want to then allow the browser to complete the default behaviour of the component (ie, for an anchor, going to the href link).

```
$ ->
  $('#pluralize').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    document.location.href = "/" + $('#singular').val()
```

I think the problems you'll be having are mainly related to the above two point, though I'm not quite sure what you're aiming to do so sorry if it's vague/irrelevant.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! Sorry if I wasn't very clear about it. +1 to you, sir.